# space between blocks when viewed on Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I am having problem with some CSS stuff. Have a look at : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxQQpv .

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test1</li>
  <li>Test2</li>
</ul>
```

When I open the same in Android Google chrome, it looks like:

[Screenshot from my Android Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjDX1.png)

[image]
Notice there is a little space between the 2 li blocks. How do I remove that ? And why is it there ?

Comment: This is really hard for me to debug.  Could you try adding `display:block` to your `li` elements?

Comment: maybe `ul { padding: 0; }` ? Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS Reset?

Comment: ^ Both of these don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add a border of the same color as the background. It will work:

```
ul li{
   border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Or you can add the borders only on left and right if you like it better.

```
ul li{
   border-left: 1px solid #333;
   border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
```

[image: Working sample]

Comment: Works well as a temporary solution. Thanks

Comment: I recommend using a transparent border instead.  It'll still show the background, but you won't have to change the value in two places if it ever changes.  see the effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/e9n04ovd/

Comment: @PhiterFernandes In what browser/OS?  I just checked it against the modern ones and even some mobile ones (using browser stack)

Comment: "The background style of the content, padding, and border areas of a box is specified by the 'background' property of the generating element. Margin backgrounds are always transparent." [W3C Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).  Only margins have always transparent backgrounds.  Content, Border, and Padding boxes use the content background.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense... Did you check the box model graphic in the styles tab?  It clearly shows a 16px border for the fiddle on the latest chrome: http://i.imgur.com/uy2Va5B.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set the **li css rule** `margin:0` and `padding:0` to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: block` to your li element:

```
ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Which Android device / version are you testing on? I wasn't able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You can reproduce the android compatibility issues by using developer tools on chrome. Your solution wouldn't work, btw

Comment: I was testing on actual devices (and some emulators) using browserstack.com. Android 4.4 on Samsung Galaxy S5, Google Nexus 5, and Galaxy S3 (emulated) all worked as expected without the border.

Comment: Could it be an outline instead of a border? `li { outline: none !important; }` . Added !important to test against :focus and :active states.

Comment: `li` is a block element by default.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is to use another div which spans in the background of both of these divs with the same colour. My webapp had more than 20 consecutive such blocks. Hence adding border to them didnt work well. This solution works the best.